# How to stop a google script from running after user presses a cancel button?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to stop my code from further running after a user presses a CANCEL button on a Google Spreadsheet application, with no luck.

My code is as follows:

```
function getRevision() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt("REVISÃO:", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var revision = response.getResponseText();
  if (response == ui.Button.OK) {
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function mapadocDocument() {
  if (getRevision() === false) {
    return;
  } else {
    var revision = getRevision();
  }
}
```

I've used another very similar implementation in my code of what I'm trying to do that works just fine:

```
function showDevAlert(header) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var response = ui.alert(
    header,
    "Desenvolvido por Rogerio Schmitt",
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL
  );

  if (response == ui.Button.OK) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function linksDocument() {
  if (!showDevAlert("LINKS - HAHNE")) {
    return;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For prompt you have to use `response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK`